# Notation to select a real number in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

Having $\lambda_{j}=\left\{ 0.9,0.3,0.01,0.02,0.001,0.002\right\} $ we want to select the first real that goes against the decreasing motion, in this case $0.02$. How I can mathematically notate this? I can give an explanation using a function, but I would prefer to find a more intuitive notation. Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you’re looking for is
$$\lambda_{k_0},\,~\,~\,~k_0:=\min\{k:\lambda_k>\lambda_{k-1}\}\,.$$

Comment: That selects the index. You want $\lambda_k$ at the left of the colon.
Edit: oh no I'm dumb.. Sorry.

Comment: @Jackozee Hakkiuz: I’ve revised the answer.

Comment: Yeah I felt something was odd but pointed to the wrong thing haha :( i think it's quite clear now.

Comment: Excellent! @JackozeeHakkiuz